# 'Doesn't have the matching return type of'; create wcf service using data entity with two variable stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015

This is my first attempt to create WCF service using data entity.

I have a simple stored procedure to find address with specified number of return.

Stored procedure (prcGetCOBAddress):

```
SELECT TOP (@NumberOfRecord)
    *
FROM
    COB_ADDRESS
WHERE
    ADD_FULL LIKE '%' + @FullAddress + '%'
```

`IService1.cs`:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    COB_ADDRESS FindAddress(int NumReturn, string FullAdd);
}
```

`Service1.svc.cs`:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public COB_ADDRESS[] FindAddress(int NumReturn, string FullAdd)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TestingEntities de = new TestingEntities())
            {
                return de.prcGetCOBAddress(NumReturn, FullAdd)
                         .Select(p => new COB_ADDRESS
                         {
                             UID_NUM = p.UID_NUM,
                             ADD_FULL = p.ADD_FULL
                         }).ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }        
}
```

I got the squirrelly underline below `IService1` and error message says `Service1` does not implement interface member `IService1.FindAddress(int, string)`. `Service1.FindAddress(int, string)}` cannot implement `IService1.FindAddress(int, string)` because it does not have the matching return type of `COB_ADDRESS`.

Can anyone help me out what I'm missing?

Comment: Your interface returns a single `COB_ADDRESS` but the implementation returns an array `COB_ADDRESS[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PaulAbbott says, the interface and its implementation does not match. Your interface is:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    COB_ADDRESS FindAddress(int NumReturn, string FullAdd);
}
```

and it should be:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    COB_ADDRESS[] FindAddress(int NumReturn, string FullAdd);
}
```